# How to convert timestamp to string when using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code and I need the original time stamp as string (2021-02-09T12:03:40Z) in the dictionary. Please can you advise me how to do that?

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
        
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['D0'],
                          'date': pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2021-02-09T12:03:40Z']))}
                          )
        print(df1)

        dictionary = df1.to_dict('records')
        print(dictionary)

        

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Current output gives me this format, which I can not use in API method:

```
[{'id': 'D0', 'date': Timestamp('2021-02-09 12:03:40+0000', tz='UTC')}]
```

What I need is the original format **2021-02-09T12:03:40Z**.

**Solution:**

```
def main():

        print(sys.version)
        
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['D0'],
                          'date': pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2021-02-09T12:03:40Z']))}
                          )
        print(df1)

        df1['date']  = df1.date.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%TZ")

        dictionary = df1.to_dict('records')
        print(dictionary)

        

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.dt.strftime` for string formatting of the Timestamp

```py
>>> df1.date.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%TZ")
0    2021-02-09T12:03:40Z
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Its working. The VS CODE just does not recognizes the dt function and its not highlighted. Thank you.